# How can I get the result of ls into a variable in bash Script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm a novice at `bash` (more like less than a novice). Trying to get the results of this into a variable

```
ssh root@HOST "ls -tr /path/to/files/Backups | tail -1"
```

This is what I have

```
#!/bin/bash
STR=ssh root@HOST "ls -tr /path/to/files/Backups | tail -1"
echo $STR
```

It returns `myscript.sh: command not found`

Script is located in the `~/Desktop/scripts`
I am running it in that directory by typing `test.sh`

How do I format the line for the variable?

Comment: It is usualy a bad practice to use ls to get filenames from a script ; here you mention a backup path I guess you have dates or order number in the filename itself this sould be a better method to select your file names

Comment: Edit question to show: Where have you stored the script? How are you running it?

Comment: The issue is most likely that they are not pointing to the path of the script (`./myscript.sh`) otherwise the error would be `./myscript.sh: command not found`

Comment: Thanks to all for the suggestions. @francoisP thanks for the suggestion I may go another way now.

Comment: @francoisP I don't see any problem with what OP is trying to do. Just the original problem noted by the OP. And the script not being found, because not being called properly.

Comment: Also note variable name should be lower case. And scripts should not end with `.sh`. There should be no file-name-extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str="$(ssh root@HOST "ls -tr /path/to/files/Backups | tail -1")"`

to assign the result to the variable. However that is not the error that you are currently on. You are having trouble running your script. Use an absolute or relative path. e.g. `./my-script`

Comment: Better sort out the citation marks here, or it won't work.

Comment: @Bex: What's a citation mark and...what?